# How to access the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have mapped the database in the edmx file from the database. Now how do I use linq to make a query?

here is an example of my problem

```
var Found = from o in ??????
```

What suppose to go in the question marks. How do I find what suppose to go in the question marks. I have tried many tutorials but that do not tell you exactly how to use Linq.

Comment: You could use Google though couldn't you?

Comment: Yea..I have searched all over google to find the answer to this problem but I could not find a solution? Every tutorial posts the linq code but does not explain how they came about the code in the linq query

Comment: Have you spent any time researching LINQ? The syntax is identical whether you're accessing Entity Framework or an XML file, or an array of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, Entity Framework generates an ObjectContext for you. You should know the name of your ObjectContext class.
Then to query using LINQ you can do something line that

```
using(var context = new NorthwindContext())
{
   var query = from p in context.ProductsSet select p;
   // then loop through your query instance.
}
```

The above example is very simple you should have a look at http://thedatafarm.com/blog/ for better tutorials

Comment: Hmmm..How do you find out the name of the ObjectContext?

Comment: @luke101: it's the name you defined in the entity model wizard (usually SomethingEntities)